# Problem to add a root property to a vue app

Tags: vue.js

Could someone tell me what is wrong with this setup, where I want to load a config.json file before the vue app is created and access the config in the components with this.$root.config. There is no root config element I can access? Missing something? Thanks for your help! The config.json file is correctly loaded, can log the config to the console. But it is not added to the root properties from Vue?

```
fetch('/config.json')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(config => {
    createApp(App, {
        data() {
            return config
        },
        created() {
            console.log(this.$root.config);
        }
    }).use(store).use(router).use(i18n).mount('#app');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you place in `data` won't be found in `$root` but, as Abdelillah pointed out, in `$root.$data`. Since App ***is*** the root component, though, you can just use `this.config`. In any subcomponent, you'd have to use `this.$root.$data.config`.

But Vue 3 provides a cleaner alternative to provide data to any component in your app: [config.globalProperties](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#vue-prototype-replaced-by-config-globalproperties).

Example:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({});
app.component('test', {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.config);
  }
});  

Promise.resolve({
  foo: 'bar'
}).then(config => {
  app.config.globalProperties.config = config;
  app.mount('#app');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test />
</div>
```

As you can see, logging `<test>`'s `.config` outputs the `globalProperty.config` set on the `app`, and it's going to be the same for any component in the app.

If you want to provide data to any descendants of current component (no matter how deep, skipping intermediary parents), you could use [provide/inject](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#provide-inject). While I find this particularly useful for providing some data to all the children of a particular component (and not to the rest of the app's components), it can obviously be used on the root component, which would make the `provide` available cross-app via `inject` wherever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

there is no property called `config` on your data, what you are doing is simply returning the JSON object you imported, you should be doing:

```js
fetch('/config.json')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(config => {
    createApp(App, {
        data() {
            return {
             // config: config
              config 
            }
        },
        created() {
            console.log(this.$root.$data.config);
            // or console.log(this.config);
        }
    }).use(store).use(router).use(i18n).mount('#app');
});
```